# Node Canvas not rendering image from dataURI

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas

I'm trying to render html in canvas from a dataURI, this works when I copy the dataURI and paste it in a img tag, like so:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22600%22%20height%3D%22300%22%20style%3D%22display%3A%20block%3B%22%3E%3CforeignObject%20width%3D%22600%22%20height%3D%22300%22%3E%3Cdiv%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%20style%3D%22font-size%3A40px%3B%20background-color%3A%20%23ffffff%3B%20display%3A%20block%3B%22%20width%3D%22600%22%20height%3D%22300%22%3E%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22width%3A%20300px%3B%20height%3A%20600px%3B%20background-color%3A%20%23ffffff%3B%20display%3A%20block%3B%22%3Ehekk%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="" />
```

However, when I'm trying to do this in the context of canvas, it just displays a blank image.

here is my function:

```
function generateImage(width, height, image, css, html, callback) {
    var canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="300" style="display: block;">' +
               '<foreignObject width="600" height="300">' +
               '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px; background-color: #ffffff; display: block;" width="600" height="300">' +
                 '<div style="width: 300px; height: 600px; background-color: #ffffff; display: block;">hekk</div>' +
               '</div>' +
               '</foreignObject>' +
               '</svg>';
    var img = new Canvas.Image();
    var url = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    img.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = url;
    console.log(url)
    callback(canvas);
}
```

As I have spend many hours searching the internet and found no working solutions, any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the entire code, minus sensitive info:

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var Canvas = require("canvas");
var fs = require('fs');


var app = express();
var router = express.Router();



var port = process.env.API_PORT || 3002;


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE");
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");


 res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
 next();
});


router.get("/", function(req, res) {
 res.json({ message: "This Page does not show any content!"});
});

function generateImage(width, height, image, css, html, callback) {
    var canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="300" style="display: block;">' +
               '<foreignObject width="600" height="300">' +
               '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px; background-color: #ffffff; display: block;" width="600" height="300">' +
                 '<div style="width: 300px; height: 600px; background-color: #ffffff; display: block;">hekk</div>' +
               '</div>' +
               '</foreignObject>' +
               '</svg>';
    var img = new Canvas.Image();
    var url = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    img.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = url;
    console.log(url)
    callback(canvas);
}




//test
router.get("/test.png", function(req, res) {
  generateImage(600, 300, null, null, null, function(canvas) {
canvas.pngStream().pipe(res);
  });
});


app.use("/", router);

app.listen(port, function() {
 console.log(`Image server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: hi @RolandStarke - if i only do 'Image' i get undefined. i have to do Canvas.Image.

Comment: @RolandStarke - have added full code

Comment: @RolandStarke - good call, but now the image doesnt load anything, just spins the wheel.

Comment: mh so the onload never fires i guess.... idk in their examples they never use onload as well. But they have a section for SVG maybe this helps: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#svg-support

Comment: @RolandStarke - if i remove the 'onload' function error is image failed to load. I'll try installing librsvg and report back

Comment: So reading the link posted by @RolandStarke, we see they expect librsvg for the rendering of svg Images. However, here you are trying to draw a foreignObject which contains HTML. And librsvg won't support that. => Either use an headless browser to rasterize it, either forget about this horrible foreignObject hack..

Comment: thanks @Kaiido, do you have any suggestions for a headless browser or an alternative this this method?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with this process on node side myself, but I would check https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md and phantomjs. Chrome-head-less might be able to render your svg with foreignObject, and both will be able to render your html directly.

Comment: @RolandStarke - ok, no luck with librsvg or Buffer.from(data), just spins the wheel and eventually times out.